# get last number part of a String in PL/SQL

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

In PL/SQL, is there any way to calculate next serial number from another one like 'A1B0010C'. Next serial no will be A1B0011C (+1). My idea is retrieve number part, increase it get return string back. 
I can do this in java, but passing more than 1000 elements to Oracle will cause problems in IN clause. 
So please help, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: one way will be write function that will accept your id and return the incremented id in that you can write sub string of specified integer and then increment by one

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to get '0010' part, increase to '0011' and return back to rest of the string. I'm trying to do it with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace function nextSerial(s in varchar2) return varchar2 as
  i integer;
  done boolean := false;
  c char;
  newserial varchar2(4000);
begin
  newserial := s;

  i := length(newserial);
  while i>0 and not done loop
    c := substr(newserial, i, 1);
    if c='9' then
      newserial := substr(newserial, 1, i-1) || '0' || substr(newserial, i+1);
    elsif c>='0' and c<='8' then
      c := chr(ascii(c)+1);
      newserial := substr(newserial, 1, i-1) || c || substr(newserial, i+1);
      done := true;
    end if;
    i := i-1;
  end loop;

  if not done then
    newserial := '1' || newserial;
  end if;

  return newserial;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to write some recursive function like this

This Function returns next character. ex: D after C. 0 after Z.

```
create or replace function get_next_character(ch char)
return char
is
result_ch char(1) := ch;
begin

IF UPPER(ch) = 'Z' or ch = '9' THEN
  result_ch := 'A';
ELSE
  result_ch := chr(ascii(ch) + 1);
END IF;

return upper(result_ch);
end get_next_character;
```

and this is your actual function which returns the next serial number
So, it generates '**A1B0010D**' if your input is '**A1B0010C**'

```
create or replace function get_next_serial(p_serial IN varchar2)  -- PASS THE REQUIRED ARGUMENTS
    return varchar2
    IS
    v_ret_serial varchar2(100);
    v_in_serial varchar2(100) := p_serial;
    tmp varchar2(100);
    last_char char(1);
    begin

    tmp := v_in_serial;

    for i in reverse 1..length(v_in_serial) loop

      last_char := substr(tmp, length(tmp));
      last_char := get_next_character(last_char);

      tmp := substr(v_in_serial, 1, length(tmp)-1);
      v_in_serial := substr(v_in_serial, 1, i-1) || last_char || substr(v_in_serial, i+1);

      IF last_char <> 'A' then
        exit;
      END IF;
    end loop;

    IF last_char = 'A' THEN
      v_in_serial:= 'A'||v_in_serial;
    END IF;
    return UPPER(v_in_serial);

    exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
      return 'AA';
    when others then
      return null;
    end get_next_serial;
```

you can call this function (get_next_serial('abc')) where ever you want;

```
select get_next_serial('ALK0989KJ') from dual
```

You can place these two functions in a package and use at your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using the following mix of `Regexp_*` functions:

```
SQL> with t1 as(
  2    select 'A1B0010C' col from dual
  3  )
  4  select regexp_replace(col, '[[:digit:]]+'
  5                       , to_char(to_number(regexp_substr(col, '[[:digit:]]+',1,2) + 1), 'fm0000')
  6                       , 1
  7                       , 2
  8                       ) as Res
  9    from t1
 10  ;

RES
------------
A1B0011C
```

**UPDATE** In response to the comment.

```
SQL> with t1 as(
  2        select 'A1B0010C'     col from dual union all
  3        select 'A1B0010C2'    col from dual union all
  4        select 'A1B0012C001'  col from dual union all
  5        select 'S000001'      col from dual
  6      )
  7  select col
  8       , regexp_replace(col
  9                       , '([[:digit:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+$|$)'
 10                       ,  LPad(to_char(to_number(num) + 1), length(num), '0') || '\2'
 11                       ) as Res
 12    from (select col
 13               , regexp_substr(col, '([[:digit:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+$|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 1) as num
 14             from t1
 15            )
 16  ;

COL            RES
-----------    -----------------
A1B0010C       A1B0011C
A1B0010C2      A1B0010C3
A1B0012C001    A1B0012C002
S000001        S000002
```

Comment: Thanks Krasnov, this solution solve the case. This function get the second number sequence it can find, but actually I want to get the **last occurrence** of number sequence. Like the case 'S00001' get **0001** or 'A1B0010C02' get **02**. Do you have any idea how to solve it.

Comment: @VnMa In your question, and then in your comment you clearly state `I want to get '0010' part, increase to '0011' and return back to rest of the string` and now you are saying that you want something different. Where is the truth? Please be clear about your requirements.

Comment: Hi Krasnov. First of all I'm sorry for the unclear description of my question. The **'A1B0011C'** is a specific case of my problems, same to **'S00001'** and **'A1B0010C02'**. I want to increase the last number sequence of the serial string. When solve this, I think there must be a way to do this with regex functions. And I posted the question here. You suggest 1 good solution, and I really appreciate it. But it does not cover all the case of my problems. While @ammoQ provide a manual but efficient way( in my case). So I think I should choose his to be the correct answer.

Comment: If this make you feel sad, I am really sorry about it.

Comment: @VnMa Thanks for elaboration. `So I think I should choose his to be the correct answer`. Of course.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - you can use `(\d+)(\D*)$` instead of `([[:digit:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+$|$)` :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff POSIX or Perl extension - personal preferences, I think. But `+$|$` could be definitely replaced by `([[:alpha:]]*`)$. The `(\d+)(\D*)$` is definitely shorter. Thanks Egor.